# Disabling a particular column of the DataGrid

Tags: java, swing, datagrid

I have a database grid that shows the data fetching it from the database, here it is:

```
String[] fields={"Comp_Code_No","Building_No","Flat_No","Current_Reading","Previous_Reading","Consumption"};
editConsumptionGrid=new UIGrid("Select Comp_Code_No,Building_No,Flat_No,Current_Reading,Previous_Reading,Consumption from Consumption.empty_consumption",fields, MainApp.initDB);
editConsumptionGrid.getComponent().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));
gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=0;
gbc.ipadx=135;
gbc.ipady=70;
gbc.weightx=5;
gbc.gridwidth=0;
gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gridPanel.add(editConsumptionGrid.getComponent(), gbc);
```

what we are doing here is we are passing query in the first parameter, names of columns in database table in second, and database connection object in third, it is working fine, now what I want to do is I want to set only consumption column of the dataGrid i.e `editCinsumptionGrid` in this case, editable. I can set entire grid uneditable by `setEditable(false)`, but how do I set only consumption column editable and rest of all uneditable?

Comment: What swing component are you using?  This is not a very helpful snippet of code.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not feasible sir, as the values and the num of cells in that column is dynamic.

You don't have to return `false` for *every* cell in the column. Since you want the *last* column to be editable, just return `true` for that column index.

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    return col == getColumnCount() - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (because I have no other choice) that you're using a `JTable`, the way to disable a cell is to override the [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29) and override the `isCellEditable` method.  Since you want this on a whole column, just return false on every cell in that column.

Comment: its not feasible sir, as the values and the num of cells in that column is dynamic, as it comes from database.